# input time in 24h:mm format cross-browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, time

I am trying to create a cross-browser time input.

```
<input type="time" value="22:14" tabindex="0"></input>
```

The problem is it decides whether to display time in am/pm format or in 24h format on its own. And some browsers do not support it and display a text input instead.

Is there a library for this purpose? Or the only way is to write a custom script for a text input to make it look like a time input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good library - *jQuery Based, cross-browser UI Library - **[w2ui](http://w2ui.com/web/home)!***

More information on its DATE and TIME controls: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-date

```
<div> <input type="eu-time"> </div>
```

And a simple script for this:

```
$('input[type=eu-time]').w2field('time',  { format: 'h24' });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a homogenous cross-browser experience I think you'll have to use some third-party library.

Take a look at [Bootstrap Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) for instance.

Comment: Thank you! However, I use jQuery and I am ot sure it would a good idea to link another library to pages (i.e. bootstrap).
The Bootstrap Timepicker  is a good option though...